# "Voiceless labialized velar plosive" or "labialized voiceless velar plosive"?

Tags: phonetics, terminology

The /k/ in the word "cool" is often labialized i.e. round lips and is transcribed as **[kʷ]**. How do linguists say its name in phonetics?

- Voiceless labialized velar plosive

or

- labialized voiceless velar plosive

?

Are both interchangeable or there is a difference?

Comment: They both mean the same thing and you'll be understood either way, but intuitively I'd usually prefer the second to the first because voice feels like a more "fundamental" feature than labialization so you'd normally want it closer to the noun. That's just a feeling, though.

Comment: I agree with @Cairnarvon, but my reason is that "voiceless velar plosive" is a meaningful phoneme description in English -- you can substitute "_/k/_" without changing anything -- whereas "labialized velar plosive" isn't. So I'd go with the general term plus a particular modification added at the beginning: labialized voiceless velar plosive, aka labialized /k/, aka [kʷ].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's traditional in phonetics to give a ᴠᴏɪᴄᴇ, ᴘʟᴀᴄᴇ ᴍᴀɴɴᴇʀ (VPM) label in the description of consonants. This kind of label corresponds to the entry that such a consonant would have according to the International Phonetic Association IPA chart. So you can think of the VPM label as a kind of name for that type of consonant. Any further phonetic detail, for example devoicing, labialisation, nasalisation, usually comes before the VPM label. In other words, it functions as a modifier (think descriptor) of the more general three part name for that consonant. (I am not implying that the VPM label constitutes a compound noun.)

So we would normally expect to see:

- labialised voiceless velar plosive
- retracted voiceless velar plosive

and so forth.

Notice that non-pulmonic consonants, for example ejectives, can be considered to indicate different manners than would be denoted by the same symbol without the diacritic. So the ejective [t'] is often described as a *voiceless alveolar ejective*, instead of as an *ejective voiceless alveolar plosive*.

There are doubtless other anomalies that I haven't considered.

Comment: Fascinating answer!! Thanks ;-)